# Как адаптировать приложение под iphone 5?

Tags: xcode, ios

Есть у меня приложение. Нужно его адаптировать для iphone 5.  По сути нужно только растянуть storyboard. Когда выставляю галочку на Auto Layout, то становится невозможным запуск приложения на iOS 5. Так как все-таки адаптировать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно просто в appdelegate в методе `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
под условием:

```
If(CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size,CGSizeMake(640, 1136)))
```

прописать:

```
 storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyiPhone5StoryboardName" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController:initViewController];
```